# Finding the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(a+d)\cdots(a+(n-1)d)x^n}{d\cdot2d....(nd)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Good evening!
How can I find the sum of this series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cfrac{a(a+d)...(a+(n-1)d)}{d\cdot2d...(nd)}x^n, \quad d>0;$$
I tried to use the differentiation, I got only this:
$$\cfrac{a^2(a+d)}{2d^3} \biggl[1+\cfrac{(a+d)\cdot x}{d}+\cfrac{(a+d)(a+2d)\cdot x^2}{2d^2}+\cfrac{(a+d)(a+2d)(a+3d)\cdot x^3}{6d^3}....\biggr]$$
what should I do with this?

Comment: Are you sure that converges?  Factor out $d$'s and plug in some values for $a$.

Comment: For $a=d$ it is the sum of infinitely many 1, whence it does not converge. Are you sure of the text?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about $x^n$. yes this series converges...and the answer is $(1-x)^{(-a/d)}-1$, where |x|<1.